# EJS Variable Reference Error on Form Submission

Tags: node.js, forms, express, templates, ejs

I have a form on my "welcome.ejs" page. For now, I'm simply trying to output the text, which was entered by the user on "welcome.ejs", to a new page, "submitform.ejs". The page successfully routes if I don't attempt to output text from the form.

I receive the following error:

```
ReferenceError: C:\Users\hbhar\Desktop\Basic WebApp\views\submitform.ejs:2
    1| <h1>Form Submitted!</h1>

 >> 2| <<p><%= parsedbody %></p>

    3| 

parsedbody is not defined
    at eval (eval at compile (C:\Users\hbhar\Desktop\Basic WebApp\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:649:12), <anonymous>:12:26)
    at submitform (C:\Users\hbhar\Desktop\Basic WebApp\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:679:17)
    at tryHandleCache (C:\Users\hbhar\Desktop\Basic WebApp\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:272:36)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\Users\hbhar\Desktop\Basic WebApp\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:478:10)
    at View.render (C:\Users\hbhar\Desktop\Basic WebApp\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (C:\Users\hbhar\Desktop\Basic WebApp\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (C:\Users\hbhar\Desktop\Basic WebApp\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\hbhar\Desktop\Basic WebApp\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1012:7)
    at ServerResponse.res.render (C:\Users\hbhar\Desktop\Basic WebApp\node_modules\express-ejs-layouts\lib\express-layouts.js:77:18)
    at C:\Users\hbhar\Desktop\Basic WebApp\routes\index.js:15:9
```

My index.js file (found in /routes):

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

// Welcome Page
router.get('/', (req, res) => res.render('welcome'));
router.get('/submitform', (req,res) => res.render('submitform'))
// After Form Submission
router.post('/submitform', function(req, res) 
  {
    const parsedbody = {};
    const formsubmission = JSON.stringify(req.body);
    parsedbody[formsubmission] = formsubmission;
    res.render('submitform', parsedbody);
  });

module.exports = router;
```

My main "welcome.ejs" page:

```
<form action="/submitform" method="POST">
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input
        type="name"
        id="name"
        name="name"
        class="form-control"
        placeholder="Name"      
        </input>
  <button type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

My "submitform.ejs" file which is routed to above (I've also tried variations of the response object):

```
<h1>Form Submitted!</h1>
<<p><%= parsedbody %></p>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Top level variables in the template will have the names of the **properties** of the object you pass to render.

So if you had:

```
const data = { hello: "World" }
res.render('submitform', data);
```

Then you could use `<%= hello %>`

---

The name of the variable the object was referenced by is **not** passed to the template. JavaScript function arguments **never** pass the name of a variable. You **cannot** use `<%= data %>`

The value of the `formsubmission` variable is **not** a useful **name** for a property.

Comment: Ah, can't believe I missed something so silly.  I removed substantial code fragments and changed names for readability. For future reference to anyone reading, the tag "%- JSON.stringify(hello) %>" can be used to output form content. Thanks!